# To access Grafana without needing to login

Tags: authentication, grafana

I'm trying to access Grafana without needing to login. I've already made changes to the grafana.ini file in the [auth.anonymous] section as the documentation suggests, but Grafana still asks for login credentials. Has anyone encountered this issue?

I tried what the Grafana documentation suggests, but I couldn't achieve Grafana without needing to login.

Comment: Have you restarted your Grafana instance after saving the .ini file?